# Rails 4 ActiveRecord has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm having trouble figuring out a many to many for a product/category relation in Rails/ActiveRecord. I Believe I currently have everything setup correctly but I keep getting the following error when trying to create a new relation:

```
uninitialized constant Categorization::ProductId
```

My setup is as follows...

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end

# app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, :through => :categorizations
end

# app/models/categorization.rb
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_id
  belongs_to :product_id
end
```

If it helps, the migration file for the join table(categorizations) is:

```
# db/migrate/20150924153543_create_categorizations.rb
class Categorizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categorizations do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :category_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error anytime I try the following:

```
Categorization.new(category_id: 1, product_id: 1)
```

ID's 1, and 1 both exist...

I am most concerned about the relationship issue but also... I am currently having to manage these through an individual URL associating one product to one category. Is there a simple way to add a multi-select to the "Add Product" page so that I can associate more than one at the time of creating/editing the product? If not I'm not so worried about it as my major concern is getting this working properly.

Thanks!

Comment: one possible issue is that   belongs_to :category_id and belongs_to :product_id should be   belongs_to :category and belongs_to :product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# app/models/categorization.rb
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product
end
```

You're getting confused with `foreign_keys` and ActiveRecord associations.

--

`product_id` and `category_id` are *foreign_keys*:

[image]

They basically help ActiveRecord to find the correct records in associated data tables.

--

`belongs_to :category` is an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)

[image]

ActiveRecord automatically takes the `category` reference and builds SQL queries out of it.